# Authorize OAuth in Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which uses OAuth.

When I run the function in the Script Editor, I get the authorize popup and it works fine. 
But when I run it in the Spreadsheet, nothing happens.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the callback URL? It's set to `script.google.com` in the service's ([Xero](http://blog.xero.com/developer/api-overview/)) API settings, but Spreadsheets is at `docs.google.com`. I tried setting it to `docs.google.com` as well, but still nothing happens.

How do I ask for authorization in the Spreadsheet itself without having to do it in the Script Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [an open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=677) (677) on that for quite a while... we are all hoping for a solution other than having to open the script editor.

I know it doesn't change anything for you in this case but at least you know you're not alone ;)